# is local unordered_map variable thread safe in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to C++. I have a thread safe question about local variable usages of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

If I declare local variables of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` in a function, and want to insert elements or increase the element value in the local variable within the function, are these local variables thread safe when the function is called by multiple threads without locks?

Example code:

```
void func(const std::string &a, int b)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> var1;

    auto search = var1.find(a)

    if ( search != var1.end() )
    {
       var1.insert(make_pair(a,b) );
    }
    else
    {
       var1[a] = var1[a] + b;
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> var2;

    auto search = var2.find(a)

    if ( search != var2.end() )
    {
       var2.insert(make_pair(a,b) );
    }
    else
    {
       var2[a] = var2[a] + b;
    }
}
```

`func()` will be called by multiple threads. Are `var1` and `var2` thread safe? Or, are mutex locks required to be used in the function?

Comment: Local variables are *local*. Anything thread unsafe has something *non-local* accessed by several threads. Mutexes are required to protect exactly such data.

Comment: In the answer section please not here

Comment: Local variables are stored on the stack, and each thread has its own stack, so anything local-only is thread-safe. And anything non local is not thread safe unless specified as so in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each invocation of a function has its own local variables. You can safely call this function from several threads.